# local testing of API Post events that expect JSON data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a POST IHttpActionResult method in my API controller that uses the [FromBody] attribute.

```
    [Route("gameworld/generate")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostNewWorld([FromBody] WorldData json)
```

Normally, when I want to test my controllers locally, I just goto the URL.

However, I can't do that with this method because I get this error:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

Is there a way for my local environment to see that this is a POST event?
Thanks!

Comment: you should consider using a class that has those properties.

Comment: @DanielA.White what do you mean?  name and characterType?  How would that allow me to test the controller?  Thanks

Comment: well theres nothing telling webapi how to route it to this method with the `characterType` property.

Comment: @DanielA.White I think I totally misunderstood [FromBody].  I'm basically using a console app to hit this route.  The console app is sending a bunch of data in JSON format.  So I'm guessing I should just have one string parameter...see edit

Comment: `[FromBody]` does json conversion.

Comment: @DanielA.White I now understand what you meant about using a class.  So I created one(WorldData) and now I am getting a new error. I've updated the original post.

Comment: Use a tool like Postman for Chrome to test API requests.  It lets you set the request method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc), headers, request body, etc. manually.

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks for the comments.  They really helped clear up some things I was unsure of regarding WebAPI.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, ASP.NET Web Api is smart enough to deserialize your json into an object, so unless you really expect a string value in the body you can just put your type in there.

```
[Route("gameworld/generate")]
public IHttpActionResult PostNewWorld([FromBody] WorldData newWorld)
```

You can either test it manually with tools like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Swagger](http://swagger.io/), but manual tests are usually done once and then forgotten. This opens up for regression bugs where you make a change in the future, forget to retest the endpoint and break the application using the api.

Therefor, you should write unit tests to keep checking your code and prevent regression bugs. I've been using [MyTested.WebApi](https://github.com/ivaylokenov/MyTested.WebApi) on several projects and you can test both the routing and the actual calls. For example:

```
MyWebApi
.Server()
    .Working()
    .WithHttpRequestMessage(req => req
        .WithRequestUri("api/bugs")
        .WithMethod(HttpMethod.Post)
        .WithContent(myJsonString)
    .ShouldReturnHttpResponseMessage()
    .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Created)
    .WithResponseModelOfType<BugReport>()
    .Passing(r => r != null);
```

There's a lot of things to be tested, so be sure to read the [docs](https://github.com/ivaylokenov/MyTested.WebApi/tree/master/documentation).